# Removed Zeitgeist, Ubuntu 12.04 starts in terminal

Tags: unity, zeitgeist

I did the mistake to remove zeitgeist, which uninstalled many important packages. I use Unity and first it just didn't let me login. Later I removed some more packages like python-nautilus, while I was autoremoving stuff, hoping that dependancies will be fixed. Now when I start Ubuntu it loads up something similar to terminal, but I cannot write anything. I cannot start recovery mode any more (doesn't load), but even if I do so it doesn't have internet connection, because I use static IP in the network and router.

I can only start Live CD of Ubuntu 12.04. I tried to chroot and get back everything I need. But I get the error "unable to resolve host ubuntu". When I mount the file system it actually changes hostname to another one, so probably there is the problem.

But then how can I install back all these packages?

Pls, help!

P.S. I can try to use this answer -  [after remove zeitgeist, there is no unity in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191917/after-remove-zeitgeist-there-is-no-unity-in-ubuntu), but I don't know how to deal with the above situation - unable to resolve hostname. And after applying more changes, maybe it won't be enough any more.

Comment: When you boot into terminal, try ctrl+alt+f1 and then login with your username and passsword. AFAIK if you have set static ip in networkmanager and not removed it, the internet should work. If it doesnot you can set static ip in `/etc/network/interfaces` file. Then try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity lightdm`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to reinstall `ubuntu-desktop` package. It should hopefully fix this problem by re installing all the desktop packages as recursive dependencies.