# "unlock from launcher" option not working

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher, zeitgeist

On 14.04 "Unlock from launcher" option is not working. I have removed zeitgeist and I do not have any folder in .local/share/zeitgeist.

[EDIT]
It seems removing zeitgeist is the cause of the problem. I see this in the logs when I click on the Unlock button:

```
ERROR 2014-07-11 15:05:27 unity <unknown>:0 file log.c: line 980: unexpected error: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ExecFailed: Failed to execute program /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon: Success (g-dbus-error-quark, 23)
ERROR 2014-07-11 15:05:27 unity <unknown>:0 AtkObject* unity_a11y_get_accessible(nux::Object*): assertion 'object != NULL' failed
```

Comment: Using Unity and removing zeitgeist is a bad, bad idea. Check this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/191917/after-remove-zeitgeist-there-is-no-unity-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution based on the logs. Basically I did a search
 **sudo grep "/usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon" -R / -s -n**
to find out where the service is being called . Turned out to be two conf files in **/usr/share/dbus-1/services/**. org.gnome.zeitgeist.fts.conf and org.gnome.zeitgeist.conf.

So I moved them out and did a **sudo service dbus restart**. 
Now I am able to remove and rearrange the launcher

After some time there were crashes and had to restart my system. But after restarting every thing seem to be working. Might have been because of some other reason. But keep an eye out.

Comment: +1 good find, that did the trick!  Note that `service dbus restart` made my X11 screen just display the background color, I had to switch to the text console and reboot